# What font does Benz & Bmerz auto shop use for their logo?

Tags: font-identification

What font name is the text: "Benz & Bmerz"?

[image]
I got this image from a website / a business card companythat I work for. The guy who made the logo is out of business. But I know for a fact that this text is not a custom font, I've seen it before and I just cannot find the name of the font.

The website that the font is shown on: http://benzandbmerz.com/

and I have tried to all these: 
WhatTheFont! 
Identifont 
What Font is 
Fontspring Matcherator

Do you know what font this is? Please lemme know, thanks

[image: Company business card]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a font, I think it's handwritten.

If it were a font, then characters would overlay precisely... yet they don't. Even with a bit of tweaking for size they don't overlay perfectly...

[image]

This wasn't exactly done in any kind of mathematically precise way, but I think it's close enough to show there is no clear overlay.

Comment: These could be just alternate characters, and even though some tweaking might have occurred for the logo the characters could still come from an actual font.

Comment: They could - but given as most handwriting fonts aren't really that comprehensive, why use different B & z characters in a logo that's really a 'poetic mirror'?

Comment: Who knows... I didn't make the logo or the font! Besides, OP confirms it comes from a font, so there's that.

Comment: tbh, the only reason I even started measuring it is it looks very much like the natural handwriting of a friend of mine, who's been a graphic artist & 'letterer' [if that's a real job description] since before Letraset was cool.